# convergence in higher order mean implies convergence in lower order mean

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Why does convergence in higher order mean implies convergence in lower order mean?

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_rth-order_mean

Comment: @user957: Homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. For $0<r<s$, write $r=s(r/s)$; note that $r/s < 1$. There is a well-known inequality concerning concave functions...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [Hölder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure) inequality.